# Python subprocess.call function does not redirect output

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to run a shell script called `nn.sh` (which constantly runs a Linux command over time), from within a python file. I am using the following piece of code:

```
from subprocess import call, Popen, PIPE
call(['/bin/sh', 'nn.sh', '172.20.125.44', '10', '>>', 'log.txt'])
```

This code is supposed to run `nn.sh` with inputs `172.20.125.44` and  `10` and stores the result in the file `log.txt`. When I run this Python script, it only shows the results of running `nn.sh` on the screen and it does not save them in the fill `log.txt`. However, if I type

```
/bin/sh nn.sh 172.20.125.44 10 >> log.txt
```

in the command line, it is correctly saving all the data into the file `log.txt`. Any ideas on what goes wrong?

Comment: subprocess.call is doing you the favor of escaping the sequence for you. Consider the situation where the output file name is given by the user, and the user gives you the file name `"out.txt; rm -rf *`".  If subprocess.call just dumped that as-is into a shell, you'd have a disaster on your hands.  The correct solution is outlined by Anton Savin below.  But, for your information, you could force subprocess.call to not escape anything by passing it `shell = True`, though this is a security issue and considered poor practice.

Comment: Thanks @RyanHaining! Helped me understand what is going on!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `>>` in subprocess calls, instead use `stdout` parameter:

```
with open("log.txt", "at") as log:
    call(['/bin/sh', 'nn.sh', '172.20.125.44', '10'], stdout = log)
```

Comment: use `with`/`as` for the log file