# subprocess.call() problems using the '>'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having trouble with the call function

I'm trying to redirect the output of a program to a text file by using the '>'

This is what I've tried:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["python3", "test.py", ">", "file.txt"])
```

but it still displaying the output on the command prompt and not in the txt file

Comment: Redirection via `>` is a shell feature but as you invoked `call`, it doesn't spawn a shell but execute the program directly passing it any remaining strings as arguments.

Comment: This question gets asked quite often.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496364/python-subprocess-call-function-does-not-redirect-output) is a related one and I remember having seen more of their kind in the past few weeks.

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches to solving this.

1. Have python handle the redirection:

   ```
   with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
       subprocess.call(["python3", "test.py"], stdout=f)
   ```
2. Have the shell handle redirection:

   ```
   subprocess.call(["python3 test.py >file.txt"], shell=True)
   ```

Generally, the first is to be preferred because it avoids the vagaries of the shell.

Lastly, you should look into the possibility that `test.py` can be run as an imported module rather than calling it via `subprocess`.  Python is designed so that it is easy to write scripts so that the same functionality is available either at the command line (`python3 test.py`) or as a module (`import test`).